# Windows phone 8.1 the name 'Thread' does not exist in current context

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am working on windows phone 8.1.

AM getting an error the name 'Thread' does not exist in current context even adding this->

using System.Threading;

i checked this folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1

System.Threading dll is avaliable.

If i select the language in listbox. The whole page has to be changed to that language
SO

```
private void LocList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedCulture = locList.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        string cul;
        switch (selectedCulture)
        {
            case "0":
                cul = "zh-CN";
                break;
            case "1":
                cul = "da-DK";
                break;
            case "2":
                cul = "fr-FR";
                break;                
            case "3":
                cul = "en-US";
                break;
            case "4":
                cul = "en-GB";
                break;
            default:
                cul = "en-US";
                break;        
        }
        CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(cul);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    }
```

SO am setting culture to Current Thread and planning to reload the page

Comment: Can you paste some code to your question?

Comment: CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(cul);
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;

Comment: Here Thread is given the above error

Comment: My scenario is: If i select the language in listbox. The whole page has to be changed to that language

Comment: private void LocList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedCulture = locList.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            string cul;            
            switch (selectedCulture)
            {
                case "0":
                    cul = "zh-CN";
                    break;..........             
                default:
                    cul = "en-US";
                    break; 
            }
            CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(cul);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        }

Comment: SO am trying to set the culture to the CurrentThread.Culture

Comment: Is the file containing the use System.Threading; You told us you are having this line, but we cannot know for sure that you are using it in this file.

Comment: yes i added the header using System.Threading;

Comment: http://janne.rautiola.fi/portfolio/setting-currentculture-in-winrt/

Answer (score 0):

Add reference System.Thread maybe is missing.